# Php imploding array then making separated strings

Tags: php, arrays, string

Fairly new to php scene and this is giving me headache.

So I am doing api call (twitch.tv) and I want to get preview links, there are 3 different links, that end with .jpg. Now problem is its stored as array and I need to break it into strings.

I have tried

```
$preview = $json_array['stream']['preview'];
$foo = implode(",",$preview);
echo $foo;
```

$foo prints out http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_adam_ak-80x50.jpg,http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_adam_ak-320x200.jpg,http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_adam_ak-640x400.jpg,http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_adam_ak-{width}x{height}.jpg

now, how do I go about joining those characters into string, so I can be able to display image.

Comment: With "implode" you create an String from an Array. Why you want to create it separated with a comma, and then explode the values out of this new string? Just use: $preview[0] to get to first value (and [1] to second and so on) - this holds a string with the Path to the Server, so just use "<img src="thisstring">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not join your array at all. In your example `$json_array['stream']['preview'];` is the following:

```
array(
  'small' => 'http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_adam_ak-80x50.jpg',
  'medium' => 'http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_adam_ak-320x200.jpg',
  'large' => 'http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_adam_ak-640x400.jpg',
  'template' => 'http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_adam_ak-{width}x{height}.jpg'
);
```

So you can use either one of the provided images:

- `$json_array['stream']['preview']['small']`
- `$json_array['stream']['preview']['medium']`
- `$json_array['stream']['preview']['large']`

If none of the images fit your desired resolution you can use the template:

```
echo str_replace("{width}", $width, str_replace("{height}", $height,"Hello world!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In joining the array in to a string you wont have a link for an image, you will have 3 links joined together. Use;

```
$json_array['stream']['preview'][0]
```

and change the 0 for which of the images you want.